# How do I create a new root by adding and removing nodes retrieved from the old root?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am creating a Code Fix that changes this:

```
if(obj is MyClass)
{
    var castedObj = obj as MyClass;
}
```

into this:

```
var castedObj = obj as MyClass;
if(castedObj != null)
{
}
```

This means I have to do 3 things:

- Change the condition in the `if` statement.
- Move the casting right above the `if` statement.
- Remove the statement in the body.

So far, all my attempts have stranded me at getting at most 2 of these things to work.

I believe this problem occurs because you basically have 2 syntax nodes on the same level. As such, making a change to one of them invalidates the location of the other one. Or something like that. Long story short: I either manage to copy the variable assignment outside the `if` statement, or I manage to change the condition + remove the variable assignment. Never all 3.

How would I solve this?

For good measure, here is my code which changes the condition and removes the assignment:

```
var newIfStatement = ifStatement.RemoveNode(
                                   variableDeclaration,
                                   SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepExteriorTrivia);
newIfStatement = newIfStatement.ReplaceNode(newIfStatement.Condition, newCondition);

var ifParent = ifStatement.Parent;
var newParent = ifParent.ReplaceNode(ifStatement, newIfStatement);
newParent = newParent.InsertNodesBefore(
                           newIfStatement, 
                           new[] { variableDeclaration })
                           .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);

var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(ifParent, newParent);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`DocumentEditor`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Editing/DocumentEditor.cs,324ac2311809b8f7) class ? It is very useful when dealing with modifying syntax, especially when the changes that are applied to the tree might cause invalidation problems. The operations are pretty much the same as the ones you already have defined, just use the `DocumentEditor` methods instead and see if that helps. I can't verify if that solves your problem ATM, but I think it solved the a similar problem for me once in the past. I'll test it out later if I can.

Something like this will do it:

```
var editor = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document);
editor.RemoveNode(variableDeclaration);
editor.ReplaceNode(ifStatement.Condition, newCondition);
editor.InsertBefore(ifStatement, 
     new[] { variableDeclaration.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation) });

var newDocument = editor.GetChangedDocument();
```

Comment: I wish I had known about that class before: no hassle with immutable nodes not working together. Just a few lines of code to replace all the above and it reads so very fluently.  I'll edit your answer to include the code I used to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do something very similar in the following manner.
I extract the while condition and move it before the while and replace the condition with a new node.
In the body of while, I add a new statement.
In your case, instead of adding a statement, you will remove the desired statement from the body.

Start at

```
Refactor(BlockSyntax oldBody)
```

STEP 1: I first visit and mark the nodes that I want to change and at the same time generate new nodes, but don't add the new ones yet.

STEP 2: Track the marked nodes and replace with new ones.

```
class WhileConditionRefactoringVisitor : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private static int CONDITION_COUNTER = 0;
    private static string CONDITION_VAR = "whileCondition_";

    private static string ConditionIdentifier
    {
        get { return CONDITION_VAR + CONDITION_COUNTER++; }
    }

    private readonly List<SyntaxNode> markedNodes = new List<SyntaxNode>();

    private readonly List<Tuple<ExpressionSyntax, IdentifierNameSyntax, StatementSyntax, WhileStatementSyntax>> replacementNodes =
        new List<Tuple<ExpressionSyntax, IdentifierNameSyntax, StatementSyntax, WhileStatementSyntax>>();


        //STEP 1
        public override SyntaxNode VisitWhileStatement(WhileStatementSyntax node)
    {
        var nodeVisited = (WhileStatementSyntax) base.VisitWhileStatement(node);

        var condition = nodeVisited.Condition;
        if (condition.Kind() == SyntaxKind.IdentifierName)
            return nodeVisited;


        string conditionVarIdentifier = ConditionIdentifier;
        var newConditionVar = SyntaxFactoryExtensions.GenerateLocalVariableDeclaration(conditionVarIdentifier,
            condition, SyntaxKind.BoolKeyword).NormalizeWhitespace().WithTriviaFrom(nodeVisited);
        var newCondition = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(conditionVarIdentifier).WithTriviaFrom(condition);

        markedNodes.Add(condition);
        markedNodes.Add(node);
        replacementNodes.Add(new Tuple<ExpressionSyntax, IdentifierNameSyntax, StatementSyntax, WhileStatementSyntax>(condition, newCondition, newConditionVar, node));

        return nodeVisited;
    }

        //STEP 2
         private BlockSyntax ReplaceNodes(BlockSyntax oldBody)
    {
        oldBody = oldBody.TrackNodes(this.markedNodes);
        foreach (var tuple in this.replacementNodes)
        {
            var currentA = oldBody.GetCurrentNode(tuple.Item1);
            if (currentA != null)
            {
                var whileStatement = currentA.Parent;
                oldBody = oldBody.InsertNodesBefore(whileStatement, new List<SyntaxNode>() { tuple.Item3 });
                var currentB = oldBody.GetCurrentNode(tuple.Item1);
                oldBody = oldBody.ReplaceNode(currentB, tuple.Item2);
                var currentWhile = oldBody.GetCurrentNode(tuple.Item4);
                //modify body
                var whileBody = currentWhile.Statement as BlockSyntax;
                //create new statement
                var localCondition = tuple.Item3 as LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax;
                var initializer = localCondition.Declaration.Variables.First();
                var assignment = SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(SyntaxFactory.AssignmentExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression,
                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(initializer.Identifier), initializer.Initializer.Value));
                var newStatements = whileBody.Statements.Add(assignment);
                whileBody = whileBody.WithStatements(newStatements);
                //updateWhile
                var newWhile = currentWhile.WithStatement(whileBody);
                oldBody = oldBody.ReplaceNode(currentWhile, newWhile);
            }
        }
        return oldBody;
    }

        public BlockSyntax Refactor(BlockSyntax oldBody)
        {
            markedNodes.Clear();
            replacementNodes.Clear();
            //STEP 1
            oldBody = (BlockSyntax)this.Visit(oldBody);
            //STEP 2
            oldBody = this.ReplaceNodes(oldBody);

            return oldBody;
        }

    }
```